# Installing Docker on Slackware 15

Tags: docker, slackware

I previously followed the instructions here: https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:cloud:docker to install docker on my Slackware 14.2 box. I've got a new setup with Slackware 15 and it doesn't work - because there's no Slackbuilds support for 15 apparently. Is there a way to use the 14.2 builds? or an alternative way to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Found out a simpler way - Just installed the statically linked versions and everything worked. https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

There is now:

https://slackbuilds.org/repository/15.0/system/docker/

**Docker 24.0.9** for **Slackware 15**

Dependencies: docker-proxy, tini, containerd